# What does this HP error code mean?

Tags: windows-error-reporting

I did a hard drive quick test and got this error code; 9LGG7R-74EAR7-MFKR6J-60U803

Its a 2014 HP laptop.

What does the error code mean?

Comment: Means the hard drive is failing and needs replaced.

Comment: Well, this is bad.

Comment: What you can try is remove the hard drive and connect it to another PC using a hard drive to usb adapter, see if you can see any files on it and copy any files you need.

Comment: Moab thanks a lot, also one last thing, I dropped the laptop, could it have dislocated the hard drive or something?

Comment: It most likely damaged the hard drive, replace it with an SSD drive, they handle drop shock much better.